# How to $count and $total multiple fields based on $group

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Good day to all of you. I have this sample data that I want to group.

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b8de8e635da281e1cb6279b"), 
"CountryName" : "Spain", 
"SmartClassification": "Special Focus"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b8de8e635da281e1cb6279c"), 
"CountryName" : "Malaysia", 
"SmartClassification": "Investment Focus"
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5b8de8e635da281e1cb6279c"), 
"CountryName" : "Nigeria", 
"SmartClassification": "Fundamental Focus"
}
```

Here is an illustration of what I want to display.
[image]

I want to $group the data above by the "CountryName" and the total number of their "SmartClassifications". This is tricky for me cause I'm relatively new to MongoDB. How can I reproduce the illustration above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

Basically You need to use [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage multiple times here.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "CountryName": "$CountryName",
      "SmartClassification": "$SmartClassification"
    },
    "count": { "$sum": 1 }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.CountryName",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "SmartClassification": "$_id.SmartClassification",
        "count": "$count"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

The data you will be getting something like this

```
const myData = [
  { "_id": "Spain", "data": [{ "SmartClassification": "Special Focus", "count": 1 }] },
  { "_id": "Malaysia", "data": [{ "SmartClassification": "Investment Focus", "count": 1 }] },
  { "_id": "Nigeria", "data": [{ "SmartClassification": "Fundamental Focus", "count": 2 }] }
]
```

Now you can loop over data and can display something like this on your html page

```
myData.map((country) => {
  return(
    <div>{country._id}</div>
    {country.data.map((da) => {
      return(
        <div>{da.SmartClassification}</div>
        <div>{da.count}</div>
      )
    })}
  )
})
```

Comment: Hi @Anthony. How can I make the output not show the _id and instead show the two properties?

Comment: this will give you the data grouped by `CountryName` and `SmartClassification` then you can loop over the output and can show as you displayed in your screenshot

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works I can iterate through all of them.